# How to use FLIP for animating height

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-transitions

I'm trying to animate a div from `height: 500px` to `height: 0px`. Generally, one can do this `transition: height 0.2s ease;`. But, I was trying to do the same using the [FLIP](https://www.outsystems.com/blog/flip-60-fps-animations-flip-em-good.html) technique for performance.

I wasn't able to get the desired result and I'm confused. Can it be done using FLIP? or Is there any efficient way to animate height? because animating height will re-compute layout which is not efficient.

This is what I was able to do

```js
const card = document.getElementById('card')
window.setTimeout(() => {
  const {
    top,
    left,
    height,
    width
  } = card.getBoundingClientRect()
  card.classList.add('collapsed')
  const {
    top: newTop,
    left: newLeft,
    height: newHeight,
    width: newWidth
  } = card.getBoundingClientRect()

  const translateX = left - newLeft
  const translateY = top - newTop
  const scaleY = height / newHeight
  const scaleX = width / newWidth

  console.log(translateX, translateY, scaleY, scaleX)

  card.style.transformOrigin = 'top left'
  card.style.transform = 'translate(' + translateX + 'px, ' + translateY + 'px) scale(' + scaleX + ', ' + scaleY + ')';

}, 2000)
```

```css
.card {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}

.collapsed {
  height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card" id="card"></div>
```

`scaleY` returns `Infinity` as `500/0` is `Infinity`. Any input will help.

Comment: scaleY(0) should do the trickn why infinity?

Comment: Your code is missing some major parts from the demo referenced. For example, there is no `transition` defined for the `.card`, the necessary classes are not added/removed, and the translate/scale properties are incorrectly calculated. I would suggest looking at the source for the full example at https://codepen.io/JoseRosario/pen/egZPBN.